# Javascript: Change placeholder color of created input

Tags: javascript, css, html

So i created a input using document.createElement
but i just cant seem to get my mind around changing the color of the text of the placeholder i made for it!?
How do i do this?
ive already tried doing element.placeholder.style.color element::placeholder.style.color and more!

Comment: Extremely thorough answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `::placeholder` pseudo-class in most modern browsers:

```css
input::placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #336699;
}
```

```html
<input type=text placeholder="Hello World">
```

The pseudo-class is currently not part of a specification (well not part of a "ratified" spec) so it's often seen behind a prefix like `-webkit-placeholder` or `-moz-placeholder`. In Firefox 58 and Chrome 64 however plain `::placeholder` does work.

From a userscript, you can create a new `<style>` element containing your rules and append that to the document body.

Comment: As i do not have access to the css and i already know this, i will not see this as an answer, the fact that i made a userscript and want to change the color of a placeholder element

Comment: @Qyther but you *do* have access to the CSS. You can add an ordinary class to the target element and then create a new `<style>` element that includes rules for `::placeholder`.

Comment: AS I TOLD YOU, I DO NOT HAVE ACCESS TO CSS BECAUSE IT IS A USERSCRIPT

Comment: Can you manipulate the document at all? If so, you can **add** a `<style>` element to the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property to `::placeholder` pseudo element.Know more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)

```js
var x = (document.createElement('input'));
x.placeholder = "Test";
document.body.appendChild(x)
```

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: As i do not have access to the css and i already know this, i will not see this as an answer, the fact that i made a userscript and want to change the color of a placeholder element